# Remove suffix from bones names in blender python

Tags: python, rigging

I have an armature with bones hands and fingers that I duplicate from the original. I rename the original bones to something else with a prefix. But now I want to need the duplicate bones names to remove the suffix ('.001') to replace the names of the original hand before.
How can I achieve that? I'm a beginner at python.
for ie: "RightHand.001" to "RightHand"

This is what I got so far :

```
suffix = (".001")

for bone in arm.data.bones:
    if bone.name.endswith(suffix):
        bone.name.removesuffix
```

there is no error but it did not complete the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this *needs* to be done in python, then I believe you need to pass your suffix as a parameter of the `removesuffix()` method.

So, try this:

```
suffix = (".001")

for bone in arm.data.bones:
    if bone.name.endswith(suffix):
        bone.name.removesuffix(".001")
```

(Or just use the variable you already declared - using `suffix` as your parameter.)

Otherwise, you may be able to achieve a similar result with the Batch Rename feature (Shift-F2) with all your offending bones selected to systematically edit their names.

More info on that here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/rename.html

Comment: Ah, silly me! appreciate your answer!